# Meaning of `@$array` and other constructs

Tags: arrays, raku, scalar

I am still learning Perl 6. I am reading the [Operators page](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#Operator_Precedence) and I found some unfamiliar constructs at the start of a table:

```
A   Level   Examples
N   Terms   42 3.14 "eek" qq["foo"] $x :!verbose @$array
```

I re-read class Array and class Scalar but I am unable to find `@$xyz` construct in those sections. What do `:!` and `@$` mean? Is there a convenient place that gathers and explains all these symbolic constructs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**`@$foo`** is short for `@($foo)`, where `$foo` is an item variable and the `@(...)` syntax simply calls the [`.list`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/list#(Any)_method_list) method on its argument. Both the method and the syntactic form are sometimes called the ["list/array contextualizer"](https://docs.raku.org/type/Any#index-entry-@_list_contextualizer).

One use for it, is when you want to iterate over an Array stored in an item container. An item container is considered a single item by built-ins such as `for` loops, whereas calling `.list` on it returns the plain Array without the surrounding item container (i.e. "forces the value to be interpreted in list context"):

```perl6
my $foo = [1, 2, 3];

say $foo.perl;       # $[1, 2, 3]
say $foo.list.perl;  # [1, 2, 3]
say @$foo.perl;      # [1, 2, 3]

for $foo { ... }       # One iteration
for $foo.list { ... }  # Three iterations
for @$foo { ... }      # Three iterations (identical to the previous line)
```

---

**`:!foo`** is short for `:foo(False)`, i.e. a [named argument](https://docs.perl6.org/language/functions#Arguments) that has the value `False`:

```perl6
sub do-something (:$verbose = True) { say $verbose; }

do-something;            # True
do-something :verbose;   # True
do-something :!verbose;  # False
```

When written in term position but not as an argument of an argument list, it constructs a [Pair](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Pair) object:

```perl6
say (:!verbose);        # verbose => False
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a `:verbose` parameter would be a good way to set a `Bool` argument to `True` with a [colon pair](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#Colon_Pair_and_Colon_List). It is equivalent to `:verbose(True)`.  `:!verbose` is just the negation of that, setting it to `False`, equivalent to `:verbose(False)`.

`@$` is a way of using the `@` prefix to remove the [container](https://docs.perl6.org/language/containers#Flattening,_items_and_containers) from a scalar variable with sigil `$`.

Consider:

```
my $x = (1, 2, 3);
.say for $x;
```

Output:

```
(1 2 3)
```

vs.

```
my $x = (1, 2, 3);
.say for @$x;
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Most operators can be searched for directly.  These two cases in particular are not individual operators, but cases of using symbols in combination.  Those are a little more difficult gather conveniently, but the docs are improving every day.